# Modified sshd_config on Amazon EC2 / AWS, now locked out from SSH

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, ssh

So, I pulled an absolutely amateur move and worked for twelve hours yesterday on a test installation on Amazon AWS/EC2. Full Drupal project nearly completed in one day, but, I screwed up ROYALLY.

In the beginning of the day I "sudo passwd ubuntu" and set a password for user ubuntu (the default login for Amazon EC2 ubuntu boxes). Normally this is where you would modify the /etc/ssh/sshd_config and set "PasswordAuthentication" to YES, then restart the ssh service, thus allowing yourself to login with a password in addition to your keys.

Unfortunately for me I somehow completely forgot to edit the sshd_config and now whenever I attempt to login to the instance I get an error from putty that reads "No supported authentication methods available"

Does anyone, anywhere, have a resolution for me besides "migrate your entire project and don't do that again, cause you're screwed?"

Thanks guys, most appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the code you need to get at mounted on an EBS? You can unmount it, and mount it to another instance I believe to get at the code.

[EC2 Detach](http://www.networkautomation.com/automate/urc/resources/livedocs/am/8/Technical_Reference/Actions/Amazon/EC2_Action_Group/EC2_-_Detach_Volume.htm)

Comment: That's a good approach, and if I wasn't even MORE retarded than originally thought, that probably would have worked.

Answer (score 1):

I wasted a lot of time today when the simple answer was in front of me. PuTTy lost my pem key somehow, and all I had to do was re-assign it and I was able to connect immediately.

DOH!